# What are the most common data structures and the Big O for operations on them?

Tags: language-agnostic, data-structures, big-o

I am trying to get a grasp on Big O notations.  It seems pretty abstract.  I selected the most common data structures - array, hash, linkedl list (single and double) and a binary search tree and guessed somewhat at the Big O notation for the most common operatons - insert and search.  This is preparation for an inerview.  I need to learn just the basics not read a whole text book on algorithms though this would be ideal.  Is the table below valid?

```
Data Structure       Big O Search   Big O Insert
Array                    O(1)          O(n)
Hash                     O(1)          O(1)
Single Linked List       O(n)          O(1)
Double Linked List       O(n)          O(1)
Tree                   O(log n)      O(log n)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Array, to get/return an element takes O(1), but to search for an element should take O(n).
For Tree, I assume that you meant **balanced** binary search tree.

Comment: @ChrisAaker No, I just treated Array in its traditional sense. What you mentioned sounds to me like an enhanced Array combined with other techniques. It would be nice to share the extra knowledge with your interviewers. Good luck!

Comment: @Terry What ChrisAaker is referring to is the cost of finding the address of a value given the index. The array itself is ultimately a pointer and finding any element is thus a multiplication and addition (multiply the index by the size of an element and add the array address). However, this isn't really "searching" in the generally accepted sense of the term. For that (finding a value without knowing the index before hand) O(n) is the appropriate cost, unless the array is sorted in which case O(lgn) can be achieved with a binary search.

Answer (score 0):

For hash inserts, remember that O(1) is optimal. If your hash table is close to full, your efficiency will approach O(n).

Also, for a **sorted** array, searching is O(log n).

Comment: O(1) is average if you keep the load under 70%